# Using UIPanGestureRecognizer to adjust height of GMSMapView not smooth

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to adjust the height of GMSMapView using pan gesture, but it is not smooth.

```
func panFareModal(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    log.info("I am here")
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(mainContainerView)

    // Adjust mapView height
    var mapViewFrame = mapView.frame
    mapViewFrame.size.height += translation.y
    mapView.frame = mapViewFrame

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: mainContainerView)
}
```

What should I do to make the animation smooth?